# Syntax error, related to variable declaration in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
//SecondMan.dart
class SecondMan extends StatelessWidget{
      String name;
      int age;
      String gender;
      bool isEng;
    
      SecondMan(this.isEng,this.name,this.age,this.gender);


//main.dart
     MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => SecondMan(
                             "jame",24, "male",true)),
                  );
```

it is works but i want to use like

```
//SecondMan.dart
     class SecondMan extends StatelessWidget{
      String name;
      int age;
      String gender;
      bool isEng;
    
      SecondMan({this.isEng,this.name,this.age,this.gender});



  //main.dart
         MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SecondMan(
                                age: 24, gender: "male", isEng: true)),
                      );
```

[image]

Here, I can use a typical variable, but using square brackets does not pass the variable value of the variable.
It is possible for me to use only small brackets and deliver the contents of the variable. But on the Second Man page, I'm trying to use brackets and variables, but I don't know how

Comment: Did you read the error you are getting?

Comment: The parameter 'name' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
is same error occur. but im declare value of name,age,gender like i worte this question

Comment: and i correct this "Container(child: Text(name??'nullname'),)" but not sloved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named parameters in Dart are by default optional. This is a problem since that means we are not forced to enter any value and therefore the parameter could ends up being defaulted to a `null` value.

This is not allowed in Dart code with null-safety enabled since your types are non-nullable by default and therefore not allows `null` to be a value.

The solution is to either make the variables nullable (put a `?` after the type like e.g. `String?`), specify a default value (like e.g. `this.age = 99`) or enforce the named parameter with the keyword `required` like this:

```dart
  SecondMan({
    required this.isEng,
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
    required this.gender,
  });
```

For more details you can read: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters

Comment: Or you can add null operator to indicate that your values can be null too.

Comment: @Pacific Did I not already write that? Or what do you mean?

Comment: String? name;
int? age;
String? gender;
bool? isEng;

Comment: @Pacific I did that... "The solution is to either make the variables nullable (put a ? after the type like e.g. String?)..."

Comment: sloved this problem. thnks @julemand101 ;> i used "String? name" and "Text(name?? '')". 
It seems that something has changed with the update of dart.

Comment: @guricoder Well, it happened with Dart 2.12 which is rather old now. But I recommend reading about null-safety in general to get an understanding of the benefits of the feature and how to make best use of it: https://dart.dev/null-safety